# XeTeX not working on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, ubuntu

When trying to compile a LaTeX document in Ubuntu 10.04 with `xelatex` I get the following error message:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, loaded.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd)kpathsea: Invalid fontname
 `[lmroman10-regular]', contains '['

! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadab
le: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Note: I just had this problem and thought I'd post it here.

Comment: Thanks for asking and answering the question; I'm sure it will be useful to others (esp. those who arrive through Google).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bug in Ubuntu 10.04's textlive-xetex package: It does not depend on the `lmodern` package (see the [Lauchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/556071)). To fix the problem just install the `lmodern` package, e.g. via

```
sudo apt-get install lmodern
```

(This also effects Debian Lenny: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576599)

Comment: Moreover, I'd recommend to skip the Ubuntu packages install TeX Live directly from http://tug.org/texlive/.

Comment: .... and this still isn't fixed (Ubuntu Server 14.04). Thanks!

Comment: FYI, said bug still is not fixed as of Debian 7 (Wheezy).

Comment: FYI, said bug is not fixed as of Debian 8 (Jessie).

Answer (score 1):

I have installed TeXLive2010 on Ubuntu 10.04 using the ISO image file, I have no error and all things working properly. It seems that, the error is for your TeXLive installation! Try the ISO image.

Comment: Dude, the question is already answered and the answer was accepted!

Comment: That's just an alternative! people who reach here by Googleing may select the alternative way!