# Installing TeX Live from tug.org

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

I was trying to install TeX Live (on Ubuntu10.04) following the instructions contended in http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html (c.f. thread [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/typesetting-a-document-using-arabic-script)).

I've chosen `scheme` -> `customised` mostly to uncheck support for languages I will never need as well as music typesetting and advanced maths. Beside that I've left default.

After installation I wanted to run `tlmgr -gui` to install LaTeX and pdfLaTeX but it didn't work: `command not found`. I've checked .log installing file (`/usr/local/texlive/2010/install-tl.log`). I won't post it here entirely (unless somebody asks) - it's pretty long, but here is what I've found in it searching for `error`:

```
TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'dprogress.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'draftcopy.doc.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'natbib.doc.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'placeins.doc.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'polski.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'placeins.doc.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'polski.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'preprint.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'txfontsb.source.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'xnewcommand.tar.xz' not found

TLDownload::get_file: response error:
  404 File 'active-conf.doc.tar.xz' not found
```

I have no idea where the problem may lay. I would be very greateful for any tips. If there is any further information I should provide, please ask.

**P.S.**

The default paths are:

```
<D> directories:
   TEXDIR (the main TeX directory):
     /usr/local/texlive/2010
   TEXMFLOCAL (directory for site-wide local files):
     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
   TEXMFSYSVAR (directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var
   TEXMFSYSCONFIG (directory for local config):
     /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config
   TEXMFVAR (personal directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     ~/.texlive2010/texmf-var
   TEXMFCONFIG (personal directory for local config):
     ~/.texlive2010/texmf-config
   TEXMFHOME (directory for user-specific files):
     ~/texmf
```

I haven't change here anything.

**UPDATE**

It took me some time, but I've proceeded the installation once again. This time, no errors, but still nothing works.

I've run installation, than I've added to /etc/profile paths (`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH`). When I try to check `tex --version` I get the message that:

```
'The program 'tex' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install texlive-binaries.
```

I have no idea, what could I have done wrong but there should be something...

Comment: Looks like the installer couldn't find a lot (all?) of the installation files. Are you behind a firewall or router like in a campus network? Try the installation again and make sure to select a HTTP server, not a FTP server as a source.

Comment: Thanks to all. @Martin: I've removed previous installation. I'm proceding once again, but have no idea where I should select server as a source. I'm using wireless connection at my private home. @Jasper: I thought so, but when I wanted to run LaTeX the output was that it's not installed... Default settings of directories are listed in the body of question.

Comment: @Jasper: For sudo - yes, I did. For the paths I have omitted, but what are the errors in the .log file? The log was created during the installing process (at least I think so). Thanks for warning! :)

Comment: @Jasper: I've entered `sudo ./install.tl`. In opened  installer I was only entering commands to move it it (and `I` to confirme settings). Should I have typed `sudo I`? Or each time I type anything? BTW it wasn't gui but textual, if it changes anything.

Comment: @Jasper: for the moment second installation is running. First one was with gui and as now I have used sudo only to call the installer. I can always remove second installing if it doesn't work :)

Comment: @Jasper: in any case I guess I have to wait till the installation finishes although I can already see that the same errors occures (but, as it seems, for other files).

Comment: If you choose to install as root (using sudo), the easiest way to avoid problems with PATH later is to select the option "create symbolic links in standard directories". For the problems with the mirror, see Jan's answser.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` give you? Did you try to log out and log in again. Also, in Ubuntu, I think one should modify PATH in `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two thinks I would check:

1. did you adjust your $PATH to include the texlive bin directory?  If you did not, your shell will not be able to find your binaries, and trying to run any of them will result in a `command not found` error.

   Note that if you runt `tlmgr` as root (using sudo) as you should (otherwise it will not be able to write to your texlive directories and therefore will not be able to update anything), you may need to change the root's path, too.
2. the 404 errors are worrisome. It does look like the CTAN mirror that gets automatically chosen for your location is having problems.  You could try to use a different mirror.  Find another nearby mirror [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/CTAN.sites) and then use the `-repository` option with the chosen mirror's url when using `install-tl`. For more information look [here](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html), and read the section on `-repository` option.

Comment: It seems I need to read a lot to learn how to do it, so it will take mi some time. I'll post after. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was trying soon after to proceed installation once again using different mirrors, without succes. I gave up for a long time, now I tried once again and everything was fine.

Answer (score 3):

try another mirror or a CTAN node:

`tlmgr --self --all --repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet update`

if it doesn't help, then try:

`tlmgr --self --all --repository https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet update`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I'll have to read a lot in order to understand exactly what should I do, I'll post later what would be the result.