# How to write formulas in arabic letters and numbers?

Tags: fonts, arabic

How can I write formulas in Arabic letters and numbers, is there any package or some sort of template to do so.

> Hint: I am new to Latex.

Comment: There is currently no easy to use way of doing this, see my answer for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20666/typesetting-right-to-left-math. I hope to resume working on this this year.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you use `XeLaTeX` and the package `arabxetex`. Here is a MWE to get you started.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,titlepage,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[centering,includeheadfoot,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}[utf]
\chapter*{\textarab[utf]{ مدرسة الخوارزمي }}
\section*{\textarab[utf]{   قراءة المنحنيات    }}
\textbf{التمرين 1}:
$f$ دالة عددية و $\mathcal{C}_f$ منحناها البياني. إليك جدول تغيراتها
\end{arab}
\[\begin{tabvar}{|C|CCCCLCRCCCC|} \hline
x &-\infty & &0 & & & & & & 1 & &+\infty
\\ \hline
f'(x) & &- & \barre{} &- & &\dbarre & &- & \barre{0} &+ &
\\ \hline
\niveau{2}{3}f(x)
&\niveau{3}{3}+\infty &\decroit
&\barre{0} &\decroit
&-\infty &\dbarre &\niveau{3}{3}+\infty &\decroit
&\barre{\frac{3}{2}} &\croit
&+\infty
\\ \hline
\end{tabvar}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For typesetting Arabic assuming you have access to an Arabic keyboard layout, you should just use XeLaTeX and `polyglossia`, not `arabxetex`.  ArabXeTeX is mainly designed for transliterated Arabic input.  From the documentation of ArabXeTeX:

> This package provides a convenient ArabTEX-like user-interface for type-
>   setting languages using the Arabic script in LaTeX, with flexible access to EE
>   font features. Input in ArabTEX notation can be set in three different vocalization modes or in roman transliteration. Direct UTF-8 input is also supported. Since most of the ‘real work’ – namely parsing and converting ArabTEX input to Unicode – is done at the level of TECkit mappings, ArabXeTeX is really performant.

Instead, you should use simply `polyglossia` which provides the following options when using Arabic:

> - `calendar` = gregorian or islamic (= hijri)
> - `locale` = default, mashriq, libya, algeria, tunisia, morocco, or mauritania.
>     This setting influences the spelling of the month names for the Gregorian calendar, as well as the form of the numerals (unless overriden by the following option).
> - `numerals` = mashriq or maghrib (the latter is the default when locale = algeria, tunisia or morocco)
> - `abjadjimnotail` = false or true. ← Set this to true if you want the abjad form of the number three to be set as in the manuscript tradition – instead of the modern usage ج.
> - Commands:
>
>   - `\abjad` and `\abjadmaghribi`
>   - `\aemph` to emphasize Arabic text with `\overline`. This command is also available for Farsi, Urdu, etc.

The default locale provides Arabic numerals, so you would normally need just choose `arabic` as your main (or other) language.

Here's a sample document (text supplied by Google translate):

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% Compile this document with XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\section{مقدمة}
هذه هي الجملة العربية.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What about Mathematical equations ??

Comment: See Khaled Hosny's comment to your question.  That's much more difficult.