# Arabic numbers mirrored in Arabic environment (ConTeXt)

Tags: context, arabic

In my arabic environment the arabic numbers are mirrored. Minimal Example:

```
\definefont[Sheh][name:Scheherazade*arabic at 18pt]   
\definestartstop[Arab][commands=\setups{Arabic}]
\def\Arab{\doArab}
\def\Arab[#1]{
    \startArab 
            \setupalign[r2l]\Sheh \startalignment [middle] #1 \stopalignment
    \stopArab
    }

\starttext    
\Arab[

إِنَّ مَثَلَ عِيسَىٰ عِندَ ٱللَّـهِ كَمَثَلِ ءَادَمَ خَلَقَهُ مِن تُرَابٍ ثُمَّ قَالَ لَهُ كُن فَيَكُونُ ﴿٥٩﴾
]

The verse-number is wrong, it shows 95, but it is 59 in the code.  
\stoptext
```

I think this is an effect of `\setupalign[r2l]`, so how to fix this, that

> (٥٩)

is indeed interpreted as it is (59). Of course I could always mirror the numbers myself, but that would be not very suitable.

Comment: Have you tried `\setupdirections[bidi=global]`?

Comment: Definetly a good step! But now in the above code, the number is out of the brackets. If we can fix this one, than we are done!

Comment: That is a bug of ConTeXt. Write to the author of ConText.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the subject correctly, Eastern numbers are written
(1) left-to-right
(2) big-endian (the thousands digit is entered before the hundreds digit).
They are written this way in input, and typeset the same way in output.

Your problem, again if I understand the mechanics correctly, is that ConTeXt, either by intention or by omission, does not automatically recognise numbers in the text, and therefore typesets them r2l like the rest of the text.

This might solve your problem:

```
\setupmathematics[align=l2r]

\Arab[
    \math{٥٩}
]
```

This solution does not suffice if you want to typeset mathematics r2l *and* typeset the numbers in the maths l2r. This seems to be a difficult problem: see

- [Typesetting Right-to-Left math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20666/2229)
- [How to write formulas in arabic letters and numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20666/2229)

I personally think that if one could set up the `\digits` command for this, that command would be a better fit than `\math`. `\digits` semantically corresponds to numbers, whereas `\math` semantically corresponds to mathematics. Something like this would be nice:

```
\setupalign[r2l]
\setupdigits[align=l2r]
\digits{٥٩}
```

-->

> ٥٩, not ٩٥.

May I ask that you sign up to the [ntg-context mailing list](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) and ask your question again there? Hans Hagen, the main developer, is on that list; and I believe Khaled Hosny and/or Idris Hamid are, too. You will get an authoritative answer, and then we can amend this answer for the benefit of future visitors of this site.

Comment: At the moment I do not want to typeset both. But your solution does not work for me 

\environment arab-besser-sty
\setupmathematics[align=l2r]

\starttext
\Arab[\math{٥٩}]
\stoptext

This does not print any number at all. Thank you for your suggestion with the mailing list, I will sign up there in a few days.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem, in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one]
```

Source:
https://wiki.contextgarden.net/RTL