# How can I write Arabic Mathematical Symbols in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, unicode-math, arabic

How can I write Arabic mathematical symbols within Arabic text in Latex?

---

For example, Integral, square root and derivative symbols from right to left as follow:

---

[image]

Edit:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,right=1cm,left=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{arabic} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Arial}
\def\rl#1#2#3{\text{\scalebox{#1}[#2]{\textarabic{#3}}}}
\def\rlsqrt#1{\scalebox{-1}[1]{$\sqrt{\rl{-.9}{1}{#1}}$}}
\def\rlint#1#2{\scalebox{-1}[1]{$\displaystyle\int\limits_{%
\rl{-.8}{.8}{#1}}^{\rl{-.8}{.8}{#2}}$}}
\def\rlqwa#1#2{\scalebox{-1}[1]{$\rl{-1}{1}{#1}^{\rl{-1}{1}{#2}}$}}
\def\rllim#1{\scalebox{1}[1]{$\underset{\rl{.8}{.8}{#1}}{\rl{1}{1}{%
نهـــا
}}$}}
\begin{document}
\rlsqrt{%
\rlqwa{%
س
}{2}$+$\rlqwa{%
ع
}{2}
}
\rllim{
س
$\infty+\leftarrow $
}
\rlint{0}{2}(
س
$2\;+$)
جا س
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21082/174620 this can help.

Comment: yeah, please see  an edited question.

Comment: I believe Khaled Hosny’s OpenType fonts Libertinus Math and XITS Math support this.