# xelatex broken: How do I get Arabic vowels back in mactex 2011?

Tags: xetex, arabic

I upgraded to mactex 2011 from 2009 and xelatex (XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)) no longer produces the same output when using Arabic language. The vowels (called harakaat in arabic) are missing in the pdf output. They used to show up fine and mactex 2009, and no longer do in 2011. I'd appreciate any assistance.. Here is a minimal example..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\newfontinstance\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.6,WordSpace=2]{mylotus}
\newfontinstance\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.6,WordSpace=2,Mapping=arabicdigits]{mylotus}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Verdana}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{There are many languages in the world.\\
\textarab{في العالمِ لغةٌ كثيرةٌ.}\\
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

This is the actual output of the example:

[image: actual output]

This output shows the missing vowels:

[image: expected output of code]

Also, the log of xelatex compile is http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9Hraw83d

Comment: I added an image of the actual output. (I get the same as you in both MacTeX 2010 and 2011; I don't have 2009 installed any more, so I can't verify that it works with that.)

Comment: I can confirm that TL 2009 and TL 2011 show the behavior described in the question (i.e. there are vowels in 09 but not in 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to tell `arabxetex` that you are directly inputting Unicode Arabic characters. Using

```
\textarab[utf]{في العالمِ لغةٌ كثيرةٌ.}
```

gives the desired output (see also [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/typesetting-a-document-using-arabic-script/12358#12358)).

---

Alternatively, since you don't use the Latin input encoding feature of `arabxetex`, you could use `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.6,WordSpace=2,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Scheherazade}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
    There are many languages in the world.\\
    \textarabic{في العالمِ لغةٌ كثيرةٌ.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for providing the solution. I appreciate the link to the polyglossia package.

Comment: @Trewq since this solved your problem, it's helpful to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark icon next to it.