# An arabic font problem

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, arabic

I have a problem with font in a file written in Arabic with this error message:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

further, I have this as an error:

> {C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/fontname/8r.enc}

I apologize for beeing late!

there is the code:

---

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{arabxetex} % default options are "novoc" and "fdf2alif", 
                       % other options are "voc", "fullvoc", "utf", "trans" and "fdf2noalif"
% arabxetex loads bidi.sty and fontspec.sty            

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}
% you can also define \farsifont, \uighurfont, etc if you want




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
This is some text in English with Arabic insertion \textarab{`arabI}.

This is some text in English with Arabic insertion \textarab[utf]{عربي}.

This is some text in English with Arabic insertion \textarab[voc]{`arabI}.

\begin{arab}
wa-ha_dihi fiqraT"uN bi-al-`arabiyaT ma`a kalimaT inklIziyaT (\textroman{English}).
\end{arab}

\begin{arab}[utf]
وهذه فقرةٌ بالعربية مع كلمة انكليزية (\textroman{English}).
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

and there is the error message:

```
\PackageError{bidi}{TeX engines other than XeTeX and LuaTeX are not yet supported} \fi
```

Comment: It's difficult to have any idea of what's going on without more detail. Can you provide the code (add it to the question) for a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that demonstrates the warning and error?

Comment: Eek. This is not exactly *minimal*, is it?

Comment: @Labaïr: Please reduce your code to be as small as possible while still reproducing the error. Have a look at the link Mark provided you with in his first comment.

Comment: @Labaïr: Once again: This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, please remove **everything** from your code that is _not_ related to your problem. On the more obvious side, this means getting rid of most of the packages and the macros (`\newcommand`), but other stuff as well. This process results in a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/); take a look at this linked question. People can copy and compile that to reproduce your problem. Otherwise, your question might be in danger of being closed as _too localized_.

Comment: @Labaïr You need to compile this document with XeLaTeX, not pdfLaTeX (which is probably what you are doing.)  Also, if your text is mainly in Arabic, and you can enter Arabic easily with your keyboard, you should probably just be using `polyglossia` instead of ArabXeTeX. See the accepted answer to this question: [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12347/2693).

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile this document with XeLaTeX, not pdfLaTeX (which is probably what you are doing.) Also, if your text is mainly in Arabic, and you can enter Arabic easily with your keyboard, you should probably just be using `polyglossia` instead of ArabXeTeX. See the accepted answer to this question: [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12347/2693).