# Insert an Arabic script within an English

Tags: fonts, packages, compiling, arabic

Actually this question asked many times before such as [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46175/setting-exact-margins), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89428/inserting-some-arabic-script-in-an-english-article), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38621/an-arabic-font-problem) and the article written in [ShareLaTeX guides](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Arabic). However, I'm using the online editor and when I tried the solutions mentioned I still get an errors and no resulted file after compilation. It appears like the used packages is not recognized.

The last choice I tried is to use this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{arabxetex} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}
```

and this for the Arabic text:

```
\textarab{نص عربي}
```

After compilation I got this error:

[image: Error]

I tried the two compilers inside the yellow square but it didn't work

[image]

I opened a test project that has only this package and this was the result: as

[image: Result]

It's worth to mention that I can't use the offline editor

Any thoughts about how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Choosing one of yellow compilers should get rid of this error, if it doesn't work it is a sharelatex problem and you should ask its support. I suggest to make first a test with a minimal hello-world document with `\usepackage{fontspec}` but no arabic.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The question has modified

Comment: You should put at least the word "Hello World" in the document. Without it you don't get a page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I copied exactly the same code in [https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Arabic] but it didn't produce the same result!! Seriously don't know what to do

Comment: I told you what to do: Try first xelatex or lualatex and fontspec with some simple *english* (non empty!) document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabxetex} 
\usepackage{bidi}%has to be last package to be load
\newfontfamily\Kayhan[Script=Arabic]{XB Kayhan}
\newenvironment{Farsi}
{\begin{RTL}}
{\end{RTL}}
```

Inside the document:

```
\textarab{نص عربي  }
```

Make sure that the compiler is (Xelatex).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works with `pdflatex`. It needs the packages `arabtex` and `utf8` and setting the encoding accordingly. Below is an MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\setcode{utf8}

\begin{document}

\textit{Algorithm} is a Latinization of the name of \<الخوارزمی>.

\end{document}
```

The output is as follows.

[image]

Credit: [Arabic script using Latex including Persia, Urdu and Kurdish لاتكس بالعربية](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veIgtdxYqjc)