# How to type Eastern Arabic Numerals

Tags: numbering

Is there any easy way to type Eastern Arabic Numerals in TeX? I mean these numbers: `(٠‎ ١‎ ٢‎ ٣‎ ٤‎ ٥‎ ٦‎ ٧‎ ٨‎ ٩‎)`. Please note that I don't want to change the localization settings of my computer to non-US languages. I use US keyboard with US-English localization and need to type eastern Arabic numbers easily.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have extensive arabic text, you can use:

```
\documentstyle[12pt,arabtex]{article}
\parindent=0pt 
\begin{document}
\null \vskip -2cm
%
\begin{arabtext}
a b c d e f g h  \\
0123456789\\
donald knuth pasha\\
\end{arabtext}
%
\testoutput
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a matter of interest here in Doha they call them Indian numerals.

Comment: Wow, impressive. Is there any similar way to do it with polyglossia package?

Comment: @Nina See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12369/963, but then you will need either a virtual keyboard or an arabic keyboard, otherwise it can become very cumbersome to enter.

Comment: I found an answer to my own question. It is by typing in hexadecimal HTML codes:
`\char"0660`
    \char"0661
    \char"0662
    \char"0663
    \char"0664
    \char"0665
    \char"0666
    \char"0667
    \char"0668
    `\char"0669`

and so on. If I want to type 125, that would be simply `\char"0661\char"0662\char"0665` . Hope this helps others with a similar need.