# Including Hebrew text in a non-Hebrew document (Babel not working)

Tags: babel, hebrew

I need to introduce one Hebrew word in a document. I have been trying to add an `hebrew` option in my Babel `includepackage` command, as in the following code, but it does not work: it triggers a clash with almost all the other packages (in the following examples, all the ones below inputenc).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,hebrew,french]{babel}
\usepackage{aeguill}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
Blah
\end{document}
```

This is a minimal non-working example: I need all these packages for my document. How can I display Hebrew text here? I'd like to avoid including it as a picture...

Comment: I'm using sometimes Arabic script, I was adviced to use XeLaTeX instead of LaTeX, and polyglossia package instead of babel. You can check my question about Arabic here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/typesetting-a-document-using-arabic-script]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not going to change both my software and one of my most common packages just to display one word... Your suggestion might be helpful to other people though.

Comment: Load `inputenc` before `babel`. One of the bad habits of `hebrew.ldf` is that it loads `inputenc` if you haven't done it already.

Comment: As you want, but you don't need to install any new software. You just change the preamble. For me XeLaTeX works better for multilanguage documents.

Comment: @maria xelatex is not the software I use, so yes, it would mean switching software.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I do that, there is no more package clash but when I put Hebrew characters in the text, I get an error message `Command \hebyod unavailable in encoding T1.`

Comment: You must switch the language to hebrew (or at least the encoding). But on my system (miktex 2.9) even with the correct encoding it doesn't work as I don't have the needed fonts "jerus" (the state of hebrew in latex is imho a mess). I can use for simple words `\usepackage{cjhebrew}` and then `\cjRL{hebrew}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure I understand you properly. If I include only what you say, I get the following error: `! Undefined control sequence. \u-default-1497 #1->\hebyod l.15 Blah \cjRL{my hebrew word here}`

Comment: Don't use `\hebyod` with cjhebrew. And read the documentation of the package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, I have been sloppy here. Sorry about that. I got it now and it is what I needed (except that I just can't copy/paste UTF-8 hebrew, which is a pity but I can live with it). If you care to rephrase your proposition about `\usepackage{cjhebrew}` and `\cjRL{hebrew}` as an answer...

Comment: @Eusebius: Please edit your question, so either you ask about your specific example (in which case @UlrikeFischer's comment is the answer) or you ask about `cjhebrew`.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg Right, done.

Comment: @Eusebius: I split off [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74150/5640). Now I suggest you re-edit, not even include an MWE, just link to my question and ask what you can use to insert a bit of Hebrew text without using babel and dealing with its compatibility issues.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg I am not concerned by your question as I have not encountered such an error. My question as presented here describes my problem and Ulrike Fischer provided a perfect solution.

Comment: @Eusebius: I understand that, but you also need to think about other people with a similar problem. They should not have to worry about whether your problem is due to one of the multiple packages your example uses; or whether it's due to your using French as well as English; etc. Will you allow me to edit the question? Also, Ulrike hasn't posted an answer, so technically you haven't accepted it...

Comment: Do whatever you want if you think I'm not asking the question you want me to ask. I don't care anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Pobably this is  not a package conflict, but rather the lack of `babel` support for Hebrew. A possible solution (not tested) is to install the package `IvriTeX` (Hebrew package for the babel system and LaTeX2e). To install in a Debian system:

```
apt-get install ivritex
```

In other case go to  http://ivritex.sourceforge.net/

Another solution is to remove `hebrew` from the `babel` options and use the `cjhebrew` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{aeguill}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\begin{document}
\begin{cjhebrew}
b*:re’+siyt b*ArA’ ’E:lohiym ’et ha+s*Amayim w:’et hA’ArE.s; w:hA’ArE.s
hAy:tAh tohU wAbohU w:.ho+sEk: ‘al--p*:ney t:hOm
\end{cjhebrew}

L'e'quation $E=mc^2$ a e'te' exprime'e en 1905 par Albert Einstein.
\end{document}
```