# Babel + Hebrew + aeguill incompatiblility

Tags: fonts, punctuation, babel, incompatibility, hebrew

(Question split off from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74053/5640).)

If you try to use the [aeguill](http://ctan.org/pkg/aeguill) package (which adds some guillemets to the ae fonts) with Babel and Hebrew:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{aeguill}

\begin{document}
Blah.
\end{document}
```

you get:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `HE8/aer/m/n' undefined (Font)
>   using `HE8/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 2.
>
> ("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINXP\Application
>   Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\gen eric\babel\he8cmr.fd")) ! Corrupted NFSS
>   tables. wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
>                                                     error@fontshape else let f... l.6 \begin{document}

How can this be overcome?

Notes:

- The guillemets are not so interesting for English of course.
- The commented-out inputenc line is what you'd need to actually insert any Hebrew, but it's not necessary to trigger the error.
- Suggestions to switch to XeLaTeX are not relevant.
- For the sake of completeness, here's an MWE with guillemets:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
  \usepackage{aeguill}
  \begin{document}
  \selectlanguage{hebrew}
  שלום עולם.
  \selectlanguage{english}
  Some guillemets: « Le quicqe brun Foxe a jumpee sur le laizie 
  Chien. » ... these should look nicer with \texttt{aeguill}.
  \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `aeguill` is largely obsolete. You should declare the T1 encoding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and remove the call to `aeguill`.