# moderncv and hebrew do not work together

Tags: babel, moderncv, hebrew

I want to write a modern CV with some Hebrew letters. moderncv works fine alone:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}\firstname{}\familyname{}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
English
\end{document}
```

Hebrew also works fine alone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
English
\R{עברית}
\end{document}
```

But, when I try to run them together:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}\firstname{}\familyname{}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
English
\R{עברית}
\end{document}
```

I get many error messages of the form:

```
"Undefined control sequence. }". File: rlbabel.def. Line: 188
```

Is there a way to make them work simultaneously?

Comment: perhaps you should add that the error is about `\thesection` not being known, as well as `\thesubsection` etc.

Comment: @heather I installed TexLive on my system using this script: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu that automatically installes Hebrew support

Comment: @heather: The fact that share latex does not provide the fonts is not the error here

Comment: I've deleted my solution since I can't compile it beyond the point where the real Hebrew font is needed -- I don't have such fonts on my distribution.

Comment: Perhaps using `polyglossia` is the better way to go here?

Comment: You are using babel, but don't 'setlanguage', why ?

Comment: I started looking into this, and it turns out hebrew babel does not like moderncv, the right-left definitions require chapter, section and subsection counters, in addition to other definitions the moderncv does not supply. 

predefining these counters and these commands did not help, it still did not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the solution here might be to use XeLaTeX (LuaLaTeX did not work for the following MWE) with `polyglossia`.

```
\documentclass[]{moderncv}
\firstname{}
\familyname{}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
English
\texthebrew{עברית}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I do not know the hebrew language, but you can try the package `cjhebrew` to solve your problem.  But I ask you to test it, because I can not say if the result is correct.

Please try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}\firstname{}\familyname{}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew} % <===========================================
\begin{document}
English
\begin{cjhebrew} % <================================================
b*:re’+siyt b*ArA’ ’E:lohiym ’et ha+s*Amayim w:’et hA’ArE.s; w:hA’ArE.s
hAy:tAh tohU wAbohU w:.ho+sEk: ‘al--p*:ney t:hOm
\end{cjhebrew}
\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf on my system with current MiKTeX 2.9:

[image]

PS the hebrew text I took from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74053/including-hebrew-text-in-a-non-hebrew-document-babel-not-working).

Comment: the hebrew text here is displayed from left to right, it's backwords...