# Arabic in latex

Tags: arabic

how to write Arabic words between English script in latex?
I tried this code but it writes Arabic text in new line

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%In the preamble section include the arabtex and utf8 packages
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}
%start encoding to unicode
%Note that your layout must support arabic text when compiling
\setcode{utf8}
%To start typing in Arabic use the command arabtext
hello
\begin{arabtext}
السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته  
\end{arabtext}
arabic
\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentation suggests that `hello \RL{السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته} arabic.` should work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12347) should be what you need. This question is essentially a duplicate.

Comment: I'm a little surprised at Alan's comment: this question is precisely NOT about typesetting a whole document in Arabic script, but about including a short fragment of Arabic within English text. This question is NOT a duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From reading the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/arabtex/arabtex-doc.pdf) I deduced that `\<`…`>` will do the trick:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%In the preamble section include the arabtex and utf8 packages
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}
%start encoding to unicode
%Note that your layout must support arabic text when compiling
\setcode{utf8}
%To start typing in Arabic use the command arabtext
hello
\<السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته  >
arabic
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek i tired the same code in TexnicCenter but i doesn't work, any suggestion ?

Comment: @user1200219: Please, be more specific including error messages, problem description, ...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek there is no error but it shows strange character which is not Arabic

Comment: @user1200219: I do not even know, where (editor window, PDF viewer, ...) you are seeing the strange characters. Check, if your software is uptodate (TeXnicCenter, TeX distribution) and ask a new question. I am neither an expert for TeXnicCenter nor package `arabtex`.

Comment: Using TexLive 2016, no complaints in command line output, but just black boxes where the arabic characters are in the document.

Comment: @MikeiLL The example works for me in TeX Live 2016. Maybe a PDF viewer issue.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek You are correct. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. May have had the wrong extension (lytex) or been running with XeLaTeX (although that's giving command line errors)

Comment: Please how can I add some english words inside \begin{arabtext}

Comment: If I used the same approach mentioned in your answer, all the paragraph appears in one line

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek , this way generated other errors for me, for example after using it I missed the numbers of the sessions !? do you have an Idea about it?