# Mixing latin and arabic in the same row of a table

Tags: tables, languages, arabic

I am trying to replicate the arabic alphabet like this picture :

[image]

I have read [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120291/arabic-in-latex), but I think I have some trouble understanding how latex and writing from the right interact.

My try, which gives an error :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textunderline}[1]{$\underline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setcode{utf8}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Alphabet}


hello
\<السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته  >
arabic


\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
Finale & médiane & initiale & isolée & transcription & nom \\
\< ا >\ & < ا >\ & < ا >\ & < ا > & \textoverline{a} & alif \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\< ا >

\< ــا >



\end{document}
```

When I comment the second line of my table, all appears correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using transliteration  code of letters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textunderline}[1]{$\underline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\novocalize


\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Alphabet}


hello
\< al-slAm `lykom wr.hmT al-lh wbrkAth  >
arabic


\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
Finale  & médiane & initiale & isolée & transcription    & nom \\
\< -a > & \< -a > & \< a >   & \< a > & \textoverline{a} & alif \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```