# Arabic text in latex

Tags: arabic, sharelatex, arabtex

I'm trying to add an Arabic paragraph in my English document. This was really a big issue for me for a long time since the other solutions doesn't work with other packages I have and if I change the compiler things get corrupted. The only solution worked with me is what mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120291/arabic-in-latex).

The Arabic paragraph has certain words in English so I can't use the approach in the question and if I used the second option the whole paragraph appears in one line.

How to solve this issue

ِA sample of the solution I tried:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%In the preamble section include the arabtex and utf8 packages
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}
%start encoding to unicode
%Note that your layout must support arabic text when compiling
\setcode{utf8}
. (Naïve Bayes) \< و ناييف باييس > (SVM ) \< تتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتت>
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]
    Thank you

Original paragraph:

اختبار تورنغ العام والأوتوماتيكي للتمييز بين الحاسب والإنسان (كابتشا) هو أحد أنظمة التحقق الهامة المستخدمة من قبل عدد كبير من مواقع الويب وخدمات الويب. وتهدف الكابتشا إلى حماية الخدمات الإلكترونية ومواقع الويب من الاختراق من قبل البرامج النصية الآلية والبرامج الضارة. تعد الكابتشا المستندة على النصوص وكذلك القائمة على الصوت من أقدم أنواع الكابتشا المقترحة التي ثبت أنها لاتعطي الأمان الكافي لحماية الأنظمة والخدمات. وقد تم اقتراح  الكابتشا القائمة على الصور لمعالجة أوجه القصور في الكابتشا المقترحة مسبقاً. ويعرض هذا النوع من الكابتشا مهمة التعرف على الصور للتأكد ما إذا كان المستخدم إنسان حقيقي أم برنامج ضار. نظراً لأهميتها؛ فلابد من البحث عن التحديات الناجمة عن تطورات خوارزميات التعلم الآلي التي تواجه أمنها. يهدف هذا المشروع إلى استكشاف مدى قوة الكابتشا القائمةعلى الصور من خلال محاولة الكسر التلقائي للاختبارات المقدمة من قبل الكابتشا القائمة على الصور بأقل تدخل البشري ممكن. علاوة على ذلك، سيتم إجراء تحليل شامل باستخدام مقاييس الأداء وذلك من خلال المقارنة بين النماذج التي تم إنشاؤها بواسطة خوارزميات التعلم الآلي المحددة بما في ذلك الآلة متجهة الدعم  (SVM) و ناييف باييس (Naïve Bayes).

even in the site the order is change, the following image clarify the right order of the words:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). What things get corrupted if you change to `xelatex`? It will really be much easier if you can use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`.

Comment: @DavidPurton No if I choose xelatex the run is much much slower and with other solution it encodes the whole document. The question is updated

Comment: What's the output meant to look like? Your example compiles OK for me, but I'm not sure what you want exactly.

Comment: @DavidPurton I attached a sample of my document, the whole paragraph appears in one line. In the link of the solution I attached the question which is the only solution worked with me, the one who was asking used \begin{arabtext} and when I used it , it output the whole paragraph within the page which is great but the problem is that the English words in my paragraph decoded as Arabic letters. So I used the proposed solution in that question, but it solved the second issue but the whole paragraph appears in on line.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. What about using \RL{…} instead of \< … >? This works for me and allows line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using transliteration mode of arabic letters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX

You can insert short english text inside `arabtex` environment  with `\LR{english text}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\novocalize

\begin{document}

english text 

\begin{arabtex}
AxtbAr twryn.g al-`Am wAl-'wtwmAtyky l|ltmy|yz byn al-.hAsb wAl-'insAn ( kAbt^sA ) 
hw '.hd 'n.zmT al-t.hq|q al-hAmT al-mstxdmT mn qbl `d|d kbyr mn ........


..... xwArzmyAt al-t`lm al-'Aly al-m.hd|dT bmA fy dlk al-'AlT mt.jhT al-d`m \LR{(SVM)} 
wnAy|yf bAy|ys \LR{(Naive Bayes)}
\end{arabtex}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a tool that can generate the corresponding code of the Arabic text?

Comment: I do not think it exists

Comment: Is it the only Arabic paragraph in your document?

Comment: Brother it worked with me, I placed the Arabic text as is and used the \LR{} for the English words in it worked. Thanks a lot brother

Answer (score 2):

I update my answer from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46627/12277

This is the new version with two small fixes*. It needs to run with LuaLaTeX (or as suggested with lualatexmk):

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont
    [Script=Arabic,     % to get correct arabic shaping
    Scale=1.2]          % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
        {Arial}         % whatever Arabic font you like

\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]     % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\n}         [1]     % for digits inside Arabic text
    {\bgroup\textdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\afootnote} [1]     % Arabic footnotes
    {\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}
\newenvironment{Arabic}         % Arabic paragraph
    {\textdir TRT\pardir TRT\arabicfont}{}

\begin{document}

English text ``\textarabic{جملة عربية وسط جملة إنجليزية}'' with Arabic in
between. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English
paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left
aligned English paragraph left aligned.

\begin{Arabic}
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين \n{١٢٣٤٥} فقرة عربية
محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى
اليمين\afootnote{حاشية عربية.} فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

[* The fixes were changing `\luatextextdir` to `\textdir` and `\luatexpardir` to `\pardir`]

Comment: The definition of `\n` and so `\textarabic` is wrong and badly broken. `\n{\verb|\Hello|}` does not work.

Comment: What’s so wrong with it? I’ve been using this for years now without problems and original got it from Khaled Hosny. Please expand.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont
    [Script=Arabic,     % to get correct arabic shaping
    Scale=1]          % make the arabic font bigger, a matter of taste
        {Amiri}         % whatever Arabic font you like
\newcommand{\n}         [1]     % for digits inside Arabic text
    {\bgroup\textdir TLT #1\egroup}

    
\begin{document}

Examples:\\

Inserting Arabic in English paragraph:\\

\lipsum[66] English. Arabic \begin{Arabic} لوريم ايبسوم دولار سيت أميت \n{١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠} \end{Arabic} \lipsum[66]\\

Typing year 1995, 2015, and 2025 in Arabic:

\begin{Arabic}
\n{١٩٩٥}\\
\n{٢٠١٥}\\
\n{٢٠٢٥}\\
\end{Arabic}

Typing a full Arabic paragraph:\\

\begin{Arabic}
لوريم ايبسوم دولار سيت أميت،كونسيكتيتور أدايبا يسكينج أليايت، سيت دو أيوسمود تيمبور أنكايديد يونتيوت لابوري ات دولار ماجنا أليكيوا. يوت انيم أد مينيم فينايم، كيواس نوستريد أكسير سيتاشن يللأمكو لابورأس نيسي يت أليكيوب أكس أيا كوممودو كونسيكيوات. ديواس أيوتي أريري دولار إن ريبريهينديرأيت فوليوبتاتي فيلايت أيسسي كايلليوم دولار أيو فيجايت نيولا باراياتيور. أيكسسيبتيور ساينت أوككايكات كيوبايداتات نون بروايدينت، سيونت ان كيولبا كيو أوفيسيا ديسيريونتموليت انيم أيدي ايست لابوريوم.
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```