# Transliteration asked of a Arabic word for use with arabtex / LaTeX

Tags: arabic, arabtex

Could someone please help me: I need to include the official name of Egypt in Arabic characters in a LaTeX document.
The transcription I find: Jumhūriyat Miṣr al-`Arabīyah cannot be used in arabtex. I need the full transliteration
that can be directly input in arabtex. Thank you!

Nicolaas

Comment: do you have to use arabtex? If you used lualatex you could type directly in Arabic and use standard arabic fonts

Comment: Like this here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407865/12277

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to stay with arabtex and LaTeX, as we have set up a whole set of programs around our LaTeX usage. So all I need is the arabic word transliterated in the encoding used in arabtex... Please

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}

\Huge

\RL{ju--mhwriyaT mi.sr al-`arabiya--T}

\end{document}
```