# Change style of author-affiliation footnote markers from alphabetic to arabic in elsarticle document class

Tags: elsarticle

I would like to number the Affiliations of the Author's names in Arabic on elsarticle. Below is my MWE

```
    \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My title}
\author[affiliation1,affiliation2]{Author1}
\author[affiliation3,affiliation5]{Author2}
\author[affiliation2]{Author3}
\author[affiliation3,affiliation4,affiliation6]{Author4}

\address[affiliation1]
{%
 Institute1%
}
\address[affiliation3]
{%
 Institute2%
}
\address[affiliation5]
{%
 Institute3%
}
\address[affiliation2]
{%
 Institute4%
}
\address[affiliation4]
{%
 Institute5%
}
\address[affiliation6]
{%
 Institute6%
}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, do you mean "arabic numerals" when you write "Arabic"? The reason I ask is that there are also Persian numerals, which I understand get used at times in Arabic-language documents.

Comment: The documenclass option `reversenotenum` allows to switch the nunbering style of author affiliations and author footnotes between arabic numbers and letters.

Comment: @leandriis I tried the option reversenotenum but didn't work maybe if you provide MWE

Comment: @MafeniAlpha: I just used the MWE from your question and added the above mntioned class option to it. Compiling using version 3.2 of the elsarticle class gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to number the Affiliations of the Author's names in Arabic

If your objective is to use Arabic numerals instead of lowercase Latin letters as the footnote markers associated with the authors' affiliations, simply provide the option `numafflabel` to the `\documentclass` instruction:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,numafflabel]{elsarticle}
```

*Addendum*, as suggested by @leandriis: The `numafflabel` option is present in version 3.2 of the `elsarticle`  document class, but for some reason it is not documented in the package's user guide.

The package also provides the `reversenotenum` document class option, which (a) *is* documented and (b) purports to use arabic numerals for the author affiliations and alphabetic-letter footnote markers for "regular" footnotes, i.e., those in the body of the text. Unfortunately, the `reversenotenum` option doesn't seem to work correctly in version 3.2: The option does change the numbering style for affiliation-related footnote markers from alphabetic to arabic, but it does *not* change the footnote marker style for regular footnotes to alphabetic letters. :-(

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,numafflabel]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{My title}
\author[affiliation1,affiliation2]{Author1}
\author[affiliation3,affiliation5]{Author2}
\author[affiliation2]{Author3}
\author[affiliation3,affiliation4,affiliation6]{Author4}
\address[affiliation1]{Institute1}
\address[affiliation2]{Institute2}
\address[affiliation3]{Institute3}
\address[affiliation4]{Institute4}
\address[affiliation5]{Institute5}
\address[affiliation6]{Institute6}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add that this option is currently not described in the elsarticle documentation. (At least I could not find it)

Comment: What you have build is what I want but your MWE does not give your output

Comment: @MafeniAlpha - Please elaborate on your claim that the MWE I posted does not yield the screenshot shown above. For sure, I generated the screenshot shown above from running the code shown above through pdfLaTeX. Which TeX distribution and which version of the `elsarticle` document class do you employ? (FWIW, I use MacTeX2019 and version 3.2 of `elsarticle.cls`, dated 2019/02/25.)

Comment: Am using texlive 2016 version 3.14

Comment: @MafeniAlpha - Any chance you could update your TeX distribution? (Earlier this month, TeXLive2019 was released.) Or, at the very least, could you run `tlmgr` to update the `elsarticle`-related files?

Comment: @leandriis - Good suggestion. I've provided an addendum to point out the non-docmentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120354/167081), you can use the Arabic alphabet and digits as you wish.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{arabtex}    % Need this!
\usepackage{utf8}       % Need this!

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\setcode{utf8}          % Need this!
\title{My title}
\author[affiliation1,affiliation2]{\<اسم 1>}% Write using \< ... >
\author[affiliation3,affiliation5]{\<اسم 2>}% Write using \< ... >
\author[affiliation2]{Author3}
\author[affiliation3,affiliation4,affiliation6]{Author4}

\address[affiliation1]
{%
 Institute1%
}
\address[affiliation3]
{%
 Institute2%
}
\address[affiliation5]
{%
 Institute3%
}
\address[affiliation2]
{%
 Institute4%
}
\address[affiliation4]
{%
 Institute5%
}
\address[affiliation6]
{%
 Institute6%
}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want changing the numbering a,b,c,d,e,f on the authors to 1,2,3,... and the same on there address affiliations