# Table of contents page's number doesnt match the numbering style when i use foreign language "arabic"

Tags: texmaker, latex-misc

I'm doing my master thesis in `LaTex` and I use the following code. I face a problem with the *Table of Contents*, in that its page numbering is arabic.

I tried to switch it with *List of Figures* , but I faced the same problem with it. I can't make any of them have roman numbers, I tried many things with no success. The numbering sequence looks like "i,ii,iii,iv,v,vi,7,8", where 7-8 is the table and list pages, then the chapter pages normally "1,2,etc".

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[innercaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[arabic,main=english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\frontmatter
\savegeometry{Mem}

\newgeometry{top=5in}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgment}
\centerline{\textsc{Acknowledgment}}

First

\clearpage

\loadgeometry{Mem}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notation}

\centerline{\textsc{Notation:}}
Note
\clearpage

\newgeometry{top=5in}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\begin{center}
\Large{\textsc{Abstract}}
\end{center}
Abs
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Arabic Abstract}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\begin{center}
\Large{الملخص}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\large{وبنيته وبعض البنيات الجزئية فيه.}
\end{center}
\end{otherlanguage}

\clearpage

\newgeometry{top=3in}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\begin{center}
\textsc{Foreword}
\end{center}
Fore

\loadgeometry{Mem}
Fore

\clearpage

\tableofcontents \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\cleardoublepage

\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter

\newgeometry{top=4in}

\chapter{Preliminaries and Basic Concepts about Algebras}
blah

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}` like this is incorrect as it then points to the end of the list, not the start. You might want to have a look at the `tocbibind` package. Though this does not explain your problem

Comment: Unrelated `\large` and friends does not take any arguments, so after `\large{text}` the text size is still `\large`

Comment: It seems to be related to using `arabic`, though I have no solution

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to delete the arabic paragraph, and it worked!
Can it work while arabic is in use?

Comment: As mentioned, I have no idea

Comment: Thanks
Its solved by [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120291/arabic-in-latex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If You Can Switch to a Modern Engine

If you can upgrade to LuaLaTeX, switching to Unicode will cut the Gordian knot of a lot of hacks.  It appears to solve this bug.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage[innercaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, english]{babel}

\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\frontmatter
\savegeometry{Mem}

\newgeometry{top=5in}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgment}
\centerline{\textsc{Acknowledgment}}

First

\clearpage

\loadgeometry{Mem}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notation}

\centerline{\textsc{Notation:}}
Note
\clearpage

\newgeometry{top=5in}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\begin{center}
\Large{\textsc{Abstract}}
\end{center}
Abs
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Arabic Abstract}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\begin{center}
\Large{الملخص}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\large{وبنيته وبعض البنيات الجزئية فيه.}
\end{center}
\end{otherlanguage}

\clearpage

\newgeometry{top=3in}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\begin{center}
\textsc{Foreword}
\end{center}
Fore

\loadgeometry{Mem}
Fore

\clearpage

\tableofcontents \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\cleardoublepage

\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter

\newgeometry{top=4in}

\chapter{Preliminaries and Basic Concepts about Algebras}
blah

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\end{document}
```

### Sticking with PDFTeX

The cause of this bug seems to be `arabicore.sty` (which is called from `arabic.sty` when you switch to Arabic in `babel`) redefining the `plain` page style in a way that does not respect `\pagenumbering`.  The following redefinition in the preamble made your original MWE work for me:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\if@rlmain
     \I{\thepage}\else\textLR{\thepage}\fi
     \hfil}\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
```