# Should `[arabic,main=english]{babel}` change the `plain` pagestyle?

Tags: numbering, arabic, pagestyle

This is a follow-on from [Table of contents page's number doesnt match the numbering style when i use foreign language "arabic"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586620). There the OP had difficulties with the page numbers of entries in the ToC. This a slimmed down version of the MWE which shows the problem and a solution.

```
% tocarabicprob2.tex  (based on SE 586620)
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
\let\origpsplain\ps@plain
\makeatother

\usepackage[arabic,main=english]{babel}

%%%%% try with and without this (arabic babel changes the definition of the plain pagestyle)
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\origpsplain
\makeatother

\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\frontmatter

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgment}
\centerline{\textsc{Acknowledgment}}
First

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notation}
\centerline{\textsc{Notation:}}
Note
\clearpage

% this was in the original but did not affect any numbering
\begin{comment}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\begin{center}
\Large{الملخص}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\large{وبنيته وبعض البنيات الجزئية فيه.}
\end{center}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{comment}

\tableofcontents \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Preliminaries and Basic Concepts about Algebras}
blah

\end{document}
```

The OP's problem was that the page numbers changed from Roman to Arabic numbers with no intent on the part of the OP.

The basic problem here is that `\usepackage[arabic,main=english]{babel}` redefines the `plain` pagestyle (as noted by @Davislor in his answer to the original question). Why should the package interfere with the pagestyle and what could/should be done about it?

Comment: language files can redefine stuff. But this is not a babel problem, but a problem of arabic, and as this is basically unmaintained it is not something that can be easily changed or corrected.

Comment: This is verging on an opinion-based question, but keep in mind that authors might want to change the numerals, and it might be necessary to change the text direction for numbers in that package.

Comment: The pragmatic answer is: switch to `fontspec` and `\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}`.