# Kurdish on latex

Tags: languages, right-to-left

Kurdish Sorani is similar to Arabic and Persian Languages. any Tips how to run from Latex.  please don't advise LaTeX `babel` as there is only Kurdish (Latin).

Comment: If the language is not supported there is not much you can do. What is the definitive differences if compared to Kurdish ?

Comment: The `bidi` package supports RTL typesetting more or less independent of language. It is used for  Persian and Arabic and I assume will also be usable for Kurdish Sorani. Additionally, the `xepersian` package provides extensive support for Persian, and I suspect could be used for Kurdish Sorani too. These packages require compilation with XeLaTeX not pdfLaTeX.

Comment: for a xetex solution, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239609/latex-kurdish-kurdi-%D9%83%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%DB%8C-sorani-problems

Answer (score 3):

If switching to `xetex` or `luatex` is an option, `babel` currently does support `sorani`. Example with `luatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, provide=*, sorani]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

کوردیی ناوەندی یان سۆرانی یەکێک لە زارە سەرەکییەکانی زمانی کوردییە
کە لە ڕۆژھەڵات و باشووری کوردستان قسەی پێ دەکرێت.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `pdftex` you can resort, as suggested by @SirCornflakes, to `arabtex`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `arabtex` package: it contains the necessary fonts and input conventions for Kurdish. `arabtex` works with standard LaTeX2e, no extended TeX engine is needed.