# Quoting an Arabic phrase

Tags: arabic

How can I quote this: وَمُلۡكٍ۬ لَّا يَبۡلَىٰ

I have already tried \RL{وَمُلۡكٍ۬ لَّا يَبۡلَىٰ} and \<وَمُلۡكٍ۬ لَّا يَبۡلَىٰ > but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\RL{وَمُلۡكٍ۬ لَّا يَبۡلَىٰ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/typesetting-a-document-using-arabic-script).

Comment: Thank you, but it is not helping me. It sounds extremely difficult. Is there a easier way using LaTeX?

Comment: Define "doesn't work: No output? Error message? If so what does the message say? Malformed output?

Comment: @user124801 Maybe you missed, that you need to use XeLaTeX?
I just installed textlive-lang-arabic and the font for my installation and it worked right away although I have absolutely no clue about arabic. But copying your example text seems to be complicated for me.

Comment: try add `\usepackage{arabtex,utf8}
\setcode{utf8}`