# fontspec cannot find fonts on Ubuntu

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, ubuntu

I recently migrated to Ubuntu from Mac OS. I installed TexLive and it works. However, `fontspec` doesn't work, no matter what fonts I use. This goes for fonts native to Ubuntu and fonts that I have installed in `~/.fonts/` myself. I know that these fonts are installed, because I can use them in `LibreOffice`, including those that I have installed myself. However, if I load `fontspec`, I invariably get the error:

```
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 128.
*************************************************
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd)kpathsea:make_tex:     Invalid fontname `[lmroman10-regular]', contains '['

! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadab
le: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
 <to be read again> 
               relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

A M(non)WE is:

```
\documentclass[utf8,12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Contextuals=NoAlternate]{DejaVuSerif.ttf}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I compile in `xelatex` (this is necessary since I will want to use CJK).

I've googled and googled and reinstalled `TexLive` several times, rebooted the system, etc. I'm out of ideas. All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a faulty or incomplete TeX Live installation, because you're missing the Latin Modern fonts in OpenType format. Did you install TeX Live with the Debian/Ubuntu methods or the “vanilla” one?

Comment: honestly, it's hard to tell at this point, since I installed and uninstalled so many times. if you could tell me how I can wipe the installation clean and install it again I would be very grateful. I need a lot of language packages so I guess a full install would be best?

Comment: solved it. please change your comment to an answer and I will label the question resolved. Thank you!

Comment: @Mårten: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your TeX Live installation is faulty or incomplete. It misses the Latin Modern fonts in OpenType format which are necessary for `fontspec` to work, because they are the “fallback fonts”.

If you have the “vanilla” TeX Live, use `tlmgr` to install/reinstall

```
collection-fontsrecommended
```

(or just the `lm` package). For a TeX Live/Debian, use `apt-get` to install all “recommended” packages.

In any case, a full install is preferable than adjusting it when things go wrong. Within TeX Live/Debian it's always difficult to understand what Debian package contains what we need.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install lmodern
```

See [XeTeX not working on Ubuntu 10.04?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652/xetex-not-working-on-ubuntu-10-04/653#653)

Comment: FYI, this solution worked for me when using Debian 8 (Jessie).

Answer (score 1):

Installing Microsoft fonts in Ubuntu using below link helped me
https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-microsoft-fonts-on-ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/

Comment: If installing MS fonts in Ubuntu helped, then you did not have the same problem or the same error message as the OP. That error concerns a missing Latin Modern font in opentype format. That has absolutely nothing to do with MS.

Comment: I understand, in my case lualatex was complaining about missing "the font "georgia" cannot be found"