# Fontspec cannot read font names

Tags: xetex, miktex, fontspec

XeLaTeX cannot compile the following MWE using `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

```
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd")
internal error; cannot read font names
```

I'm using a freshly installed and updated Miktex 2.9 distribution (the repository is synchronized) on Windows 8.1.

Based on [the only suggestion I found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168594/fontspec-cannot-find-fonts-on-ubuntu) on this topic, I checked that the `lm` package, containing the OpenType Latin Modern fonts, is correctly installed, that the FNDB is refreshed, and that the TeX formats are updated.

Comment: You could try to call `fc-cache` on the command line. But if the problem persist you should make a bug report, probably it is a problem with the newest (major) update (I don't have it yet, so I can't test).

Comment: I can now reproduce the error and will make a bug report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by a software update

Comment: @egreg fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated all MikTeX packages to the most recent development version and the issue has been solved.